# Is there a policy for indicating an Office add-in as in beta?

Tags: office-store

I would like to indicate within my add-in that it is in the early stages of feature implementation and verification by putting a note in the task pane that it's still in beta, even though I'm submitting it to Microsoft for submission.

Is there a policy against doing this? So far I haven't come across anything in my reading of the documentation, but there is a lot of documentation.